# pytest fixture injection when decorator adds argument

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to decorate test functions and return a wrapper that expects a fixture, but, it appears that pytest ignores the wrapper and looks to the wrapped function to determine which fixtures are needed.

contrived example:

```
def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def _wrapper(some_fixture, *args, **kwargs):
        expected_results = some_fixture.load_results_for_case(func)
        observed_results = func(*args, **kwargs)
        assert expected_results == observed_results
    return _wrapper

@decorator
def test_some_feature():
    # some fancy code generating complex dataset
    return complex_dataset
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What do you mean by "test functions"? Your `test_some_feature` does not look like a test (it returns something, which a test doesn't, and seems to do no testing), can you explain what it should do? What are you testing (in this example), and what do you expect?

Comment: Correct. The test_some_feature function is not a traditional looking test but _wrapper is, so, test_some_feature is decorated to become a test function. Let me update the example to be a little more realistic.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you want to achieve - maybe there is an easier way to do this.